# Redirecting Page whilst still executing slow Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq-to-sql, datacontext

For an Intranet application I have a web page save function that can lead to substantial action on several database tables. I am using Linq2SQL and some 20 seconds of browser idle get swallowed up by 3 seperate `Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()` calls. These calls occur right at the end of the code called by the SaveButton postback.

I want the actual work needed to accumulate these database changes to be done within the save button action. However, given no problems or conflicts detected, I would then like to redirect the user to another page immediately after this (so they don't have to stare at a screen doing something they cannot stop. Then as the user continues I would like to call all the `SubmitChanges()`.

Ideal workflow:

```
void btnSaveClick() 
{
    CalculateChangeSetProcedure
    Redirect somewhere...
    SubmitChangesProcedure
}
```

So my problem is Response.Redirect(..., true) will just shut things down. Is there any way I can do this with ASP.NET procedures or will I have to do it async on another thread?

Comment: Looks like I am not going to change the button event but instead work on changing the DB submit code to use SqlBulkCopy as transparently as possible instead. Fantastic link: [Implementing SqlBulkCopy in Linq to Sql](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/aviwortzel/archive/2008/05/06/implementing-sqlbulkcopy-in-linq-to-sql.aspx). It is completely transforming my insert time.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and accept it, if it workred for you. So that the question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to submit a small amount of data then the idle time you have is not normal. First thing you can do is check the submit function and see there is anything you can optimize. For example, if you are submitting 50 rows and you call SubmitChanges after each of them, this could slow down the things significantly. The solution in this case is to prepare all the date and submit it at once.

Another option is calling a service that submits the changes for you. In this way you the saving will be done asynchronously and would not interrupt the user. After the service is done you can get some simple jQuery popup or something to inform the user that the saving is completed if this is important.

Comment: Its a large amount of data. 20 seconds on the development db server is the result of several thousand inserts to multiple tables across 3 databases. The old code I have been optimizing used to submit many small chunks as you warn against. I am considering your separate web service approach...

Comment: Check this article http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2010/04/02/calling-web-service-functions-asynchronously-from-a-web-page.aspx

Comment: if the data being inserted is too big,then you should be careful that the ASP.net process will be killed when the timeout is elapsed. One possible solution to that is actually calling not a web service or another ASP.NET thread but calling Windows service. In this way the thread won't have timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Start a seperate background thread for SubmitChanges() call before doing the redirection.

e.g.

```
void btnSaveClick() 
{    
      CalculateChangeSetProcedure
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(this.SubmitTheStuff), null);
      Redirect somewhere..
}
private void SubmitTheStuff(object obj)
{
      SubmitChangesProcedure
}
```

Comment: I have given it a try but I can't stop Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() blowing up when I push it to another thread.

Comment: Yes. But at least the browser should redirect whilst SubmitChanges() is doing it's work. What do you mean with "blowing up"? Memory?